# Unrecognized configuration section rewriter

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I'm trying to implement Approach 3 from [this Url Rewriting](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx) article.

I've added all the required configuration (in web.config for the UrlRewriter module) but when i try to add this in web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    <sectionGroup>
    <section name="rewriter"  
             requirePermission="false" 
             type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" />
  </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web>

    <httpModules>
      <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <rewriter>
     <rewrite url="~/products/(.+)" to="~/products.aspx?category=$1" />
  </rewriter>
</configuration>
```

it gives me:

> Unrecognized configuration section
>   rewriter...

Please let me know me WHY it tells me that i put in the wrong place that rewriter xml node?

Thanks...

Solution: I've put section node under sectionGroup while it has to be directly under configSections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the config section so  .Net can **NOT** parse the actual setting

```
 <rewriter>
   <rewrite url="~/products/(.+)" to="~/products.aspx?category=$1" />
 </rewriter>
```

IF read the link you posted the rewriter is no contained in the  section but it is seperate.

Comment: hi...I;ve added the entire xml taken from Scot, which i put in my web.config also. What is strange is that <rewriter> is a direct child node of configuration...

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue check the **configSections** place. rewriter should be outside of sectiongroup.

like that:

```
<configSections>
        <section name="rewriter"  
                 requirePermission="false" 
                 type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" />
      </configSections>
```

Its working i checked with my project.